# How many letters would he need to write randomly to have expected number of occurrences of the string LEARNING calculate be 1?

Tags: statistics

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while now and I don't know how to deal with the multiple occurrences of each letter, but the answer I did come up with is over 200 trillion which seems way off. I'll appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 4):

The expected number of occurances of "LEARNING" within any specific block of eight consecutive letters within a string is $\frac1{26^8}$ (assuming independent uniform distribution). Even though the event of occurring at position $x$ and at position $y$ in a longer string are not independent if $|x-y|<8$, expected values remain additive. Hence we need a string long enough to have $26^8$ blocks of eight consecutive letters, which means that we need $26^8+7$ letters in total.